# How to make points move randomly into a specific shape

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to do the following with *Geometry Nodes*:

1. There are 10*10 points, arranged in a grid.
2. The points start to move randomly into a specific shape（random means some points will move first then others）
3. While the points are moving the scale is getting bigger till it arrives at the new position

Update:

I made something that is close to what I want to achieve

[image: image of a plane]

I want these points to scale independently when they start to move.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

---

update:
I make smoe thing that close to what i want achieve[image]

I want these points scale independently when it start to move

I dont know How to upload this blenderfile

Comment: Hello and welcome! Your question was hard to read. I've tried to improve the readability. Why did you number the points as 1, 2, and 2.5?

Comment: Here is the blender File [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9j9RkXEl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9j9RkXEl/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

Here I feed the current frame with a random value, and use this value as offset for the position as well as for the radius.

[image]

*PS: It would be great if you could clarify your question a bit, so that people can really understand what you actually meant. ...then I can also gladly explain what I'm actually doing here. Thanks!*

---

**Update:**

Applying this technique to your specific example, here's what comes out:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer ，I had update my question，you can take a look ，Thank again！

Comment: Thanks! But i would like to keep the grid visible at the start. I'll start try to modify the file you upload now. Thank for the help!

Comment: @PersonFirst Just change the value *To Min* in the node `Map Range`.